# SharePoint and Office Integration not working in IE

Tags: office-integration, office

We have SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, Office Pro Plus, Windows 7, and IE 11.

Connect to Outlook, Export to Excel, Customize Form (InfoPath), and basically all other Office Integration points seem to be failing in IE.  **Connect to Outlook works correctly in Chrome**.

- Minimal Download Strategy is turned off
- SharePoint is in the Intranet Zone
- IE Protected Mode is off

I suspect there is something wrong with our IE Add-ons, or that the upgrade to Office Pro Plus did not work correctly, potentially the Office Uninstaller does not cleanly uninstall Office.  Has anyone ran into this issue before?

**IE Connect To Outlook**

[image: IE Connect To Outlook]

**Chrome Connect To Outlook** This works when clicked.

[image: Chrome Connect To Outlook]

**Export To Excel**

[image: Export To Excel]

**Customize Form - InfoPath**

[image: Customize Form - InfoPath]

**Installed IE Add-ons**

[image: Installed IE Add-ons]

Comment: Please check if this article helps you.....http://sp2013galaxy.blogspot.com/2014/04/excel-office-ribbon-grayed-out-features.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following change fixed this issue for me however removing virtual components functionality could have negative implications to other applications:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Virtualization

ProcessesUsingVirtualComponents   (Multi-String Value)

Deleted:

%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that we started getting this problem when we moved from an MSI version of Office to a C2R version.

As I understand it, C2R Office uses a virtualized version of the SharePoint/Skype ActiveX component (Interceptor.dll) that does not work together with App-V virtualization of Internet Explorer.

See explanation from Microsoft: ["Click to Join" fails to invoke Skype for Business on computers that use Application Virtualization](http://%20https://docs.microsoft.com/ro-RO/SkypeForBusiness/troubleshoot/server-sign-in/click-to-join-fails)

Here is [another Stack Exchange question about the same thing](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299001/office-2019-does-not-work-well-with-sharepoint-2016).