# Office 2019 (C2R) does not work well with SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

We are on SharePoint Server 2016 and Office 2016 and after starting a small Office 2019 rollout, our pilot users have started to complain about the following issues:

1. Drag and drop **from** SharePoint **to** Windows has stopped working
2. The Skype presence indicator has stopped working

Is Skype presence still supposed to work with Office 2019 in combination with SP2016?

**Office versions:** Office Professional Plus 2019 (32 bit), v16.0.10373.20050

**Browsers tested:** Edge (with sites in IE mode) + IE11

The *name.dll* file hosting the ActiveX component is still in place as below:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\
   name.dll (16.0.10352.20042)
   namecontrolproxy.dll
   namecontrolserver.exe
```

What is the official support status for Office and SharePoint Server? I have not been able to find anything.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that our new Office version is a Click-to-Run (C2R) version, and as I understand it, C2R Office uses a virtualized version of the SharePoint/Skype ActiveX component (Interceptor.dll) that does not work together with App-V virtualization of Internet Explorer.

The solution according to Microsoft is to modify registry as instructed below. The security and/or or other implications of doing that are not completely clear to me, though, so beware.

*Remove the iexplore.exe path from the following registry value:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\AppV\Client\Virtualization\ProcessesUsingVirtualComponents*

See explanation from Microsoft:
["Click to Join" fails to invoke Skype for Business on computers that use Application Virtualization](https://docs.microsoft.com/ro-RO/SkypeForBusiness/troubleshoot/server-sign-in/click-to-join-fails)

[Another Stack Exchange question about the same thing:](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179788/sharepoint-and-office-integration-not-working-in-ie)